How add Canonical tag in Angular website?
To add a canonical tag to an Angular website, you can leverage Angular’s Meta service to dynamically insert it into the  section. Canonical tags are essential for SEO as they help search engines understand the primary version of a webpage, preventing duplicate content issues. Here's how to do it.

You can try this directive, from the below github issue. Seems to be a valid way to do this.
Support adding rel=canonical link tags using an included service #15776
Answer by alirezamirian
@Directive({
  selector: '[moveToHead]'
})
export class MoveToHeadDirective implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
  }
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, this.elRef.nativeElement);
    this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'movetohead');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.renderer.removeChild(this.document.head, this.elRef.nativeElement);
  }
}

Usage:
<link rel="amphtml" moveToHead [attr.href]="ampUrl">

